# RSpec "Migrations Are Pending" on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, rspec

While running Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2.0, and Rspec 3.2, I get this error when I run Rspec:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
/Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:393:in `check_pending!':  (ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError)

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `block in maintain_test_schema!'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:640:in `suppress_messages'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `maintain_test_schema!'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/Dropbox/Vocabulist/vocabulist/spec/rails_helper.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `require'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `block in requires='
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `each'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `requires='
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:110:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `each'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `process_options_into'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/gemsets/vocabulist/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/ahanmalhotra/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/gemsets/vocabulist/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

My test database is on Heroku, and I think that RSpec is trying to drop the test database and recreate it. This is not allowed on Heroku, so this is why the `permission denied` error occurs. This error does not occur if you provision a brand new database and run RSpec for the first time; after the first time the error occurs. Any ideas on a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't in production. This is on my local machine and on my Bamboo server. They both point to the same test db on Heroku.

Comment: as you stated Heroku doesn't allow you to drop the DB so this isn't a good platform to host your development database.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use Heroku db for test purposes as test database recreates every time before test's suit will start. Instead of this you should use local machine for runinig tests or if the test suit is too big and your dev machine is slow, use CI services like Travis, Semaphore, Circle CI, Snap CI, Codeship and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So for Atlassian Bamboo, I should just use a local Postgres database? This setup used to work fine, but then when I upgraded Rails and RSpec, it broke.

Comment: Look, when you working on your code on the local machine, you using 2 databases locally: development and test. When you think it's time to push your app to production, you push app to Heroku, run migrates on Heroku and load seeds, if needed. So your app on Heroku will use database placed on Heroku.  There is no correlation between Heroku's stacks and your local environment. Am I miss something? Maybe something wrong with your setup? You can share more information and I will try help.

Comment: I have a postgres db on heroku called blah_test. On my dev machine and my Atlassian Bamboo CI instance, I was running rspec with the database blah_test. Which database should I then use for Atlassian Bamboo? Should I use a local one for each machine?

Comment: @AhanMalhotra your development flow might be as this: write code, running tests for this code (locally with local test db), if it's ok, push your new code to CI (or Github with CI integration established) where all tests will run (CI will use it's own test database), then if there tests are green too, push your code to heroku (your app  will use it's own, not shared, production layer database)